# How can I use Band to distribute a 2 by2 matrix on the offdiagnol of a biger matrix?

Tags: matrix

I am trying to put the 2 by 2 `sx = PauliMatrix[1]` on the off-diagnoal of a matrix of size n by n. Amusing `n=12`, I tried this but did not work

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, n - 1}, {n, n}] -> {sx}}, {n,n}] // MatrixForm;
```

this   is what I get
[image]

However, this is what I need

[image]

For sx, I can get the desired results with

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, n}, Automatic, {1, -1}] -> 1}, {n, 
   n}] // MatrixForm
```

but I need to do that for `sy=PauliMatrix[2]` and `sz=PauliMatrix[3]` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix ``

```
sa =SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[
   MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], n - #2[[1]]} -> # &, ConstantArray[#, n/Length@#]]] &;

sa @ sx // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
sa @ sy // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
sa @ sz // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: as I mentioned above for sx I can do it, but how can I do that for sy and sz?

Comment: @valarmorghulis, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kglr